# Eloquent events for deleting is haltable if they return false?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I have condition check before i delete any user. So that i use User model eloquent deleting event. In that event i check condition before delete and it's return true then can delete user. But it's return false can't delete user. But currently it didn't work like that any way it delete user. Why?

```
User::deleting(function($user) {
    if($user->is_admin){
      return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put event in you `User` model `boot` method, you can not call it on the model directly.

```php
    public static function boot()
  {
    parent::boot();
    static::deleting(function($user) 
    {
    if($user->is_admin){
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  });
}
```

And then delete record like this `User::find($id)->delete();`

Comment: Thanks for your Answer first. If i used like above. Then the event return false what will happen?

Comment: it's not going to fire the deleting event.@Corder

Comment: Yes what happen deleting event response will be false? Delete will not happen or else?

Comment: @Corder it means the deleting is not going to happen. the record is not going to be deleted.